# what is the use of %.*s in this program

Tags: c

I have the following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()

{
    static char string[12];
    int length,c,d;
    printf("Enter a string :");
    gets(string);
    length=strlen(string);
    printf("\nLength of the string is %d",length);
    for(c=0;c<=length-2;c++)
    {
        d=c+1;
        printf("\t%.*s\n",d,string);
    }
    for(c=length;c>=0;c--)
    {
        d=c+1;
        printf("\t%.*s\n",d,string);
    }
}
```

I am very much confused about the usage of `%.*s` in the `printf` statement. I know `%s` is used for displaying strings, but I am confused the usage of `.*`  before `s` in this program. Also there is only one datatype (`%s`) mentioned inside the quotation marks in the printf statement, but there are two variables mentioned in the `printf` statement.

Comment: Have you read the man page for printf?

Comment: Such as [this one](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/printf.html) for example?

Comment: I can't see anything about it on there

Comment: @H2CO3 I am confused, and don't see the difference between my link and your link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The format statement can allow a width and precision value.  So, to print a string for a variable length then specify `printf("%.*s", length, string)`.  The `length` is substituted for the asterisk.

Answer (score 6):

It is a precision component, which specifies maximum number of bytes for string conversions. Asterisk (`*`), uses an integer argument, which specifies the value (for precision) to be used.

As an example, the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argv, char **argc)
{
    char *s = "hello, world";
    printf("%.*s\n", 4, s);
    return 0;
}
```

gives output:

```
hell
```

Comment: Another example is `printf("%.*s\n", 9, "goto hello_world;");`... :P

Comment: Thanking you Programmer.Thanks :)

Comment: @mohit That was meant to be a joke. It prints `goto hell`. (No, I didn't mean to offend you with that.)